# The area of a bounded, convex, open set?

Tags: real-analysis

First of all, does a bounded, convex, and open set $S$ in $\mathbb R ^n $ have an area? And if it does, is it the same as the area of its closure? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, in the sense of Lebesgue measure. Since the measure of the boundary of a convex set is zero, the measure of the closure of the set is equal to the measure of the set.